# Error when using condensed fonts on jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, css, autocomplete

For some reason I'm getting extra padding on my autocomplete when I use a condensed font. The auto-complete seems to expand to the width as though I was using a non condensed font.

Even stranger, it only happens once, then it corrects itself and never happens again until the page is refreshed. Try my autocomplete to see what I mean.

Heres my link: [www.fonefox.com/fonefox/public/compare.php](http://www.fonefox.com/fonefox/public/compare.php)

If you type "ip" it will show a list of iPhone's with the gap on the left, then as soon as you hit "iph" the gap disappears.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Getting some 404s for `autocomplete.css` and a jQuery UI `png`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Phil. Changed it on the local server still having the same issue. Any thoughts?